# How do I use same mongo database (mongoose) in more than one node app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two node web apps which share same database(using mongoose), I have defined a schema in the first app but I don't want to define mongoose schema in the  second app. How do I query data from second app without schema.

Comment: May be create a simple app that only deals with database interactions and use it in both your apps...

Comment: Perhaps this [answer][1] will be helpful. Good luck :) [1]:https://stackoverflow.com/a/21432603/9470445