# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am new to MongoDB Atlas. I am trying to query the currently existing collection "dogs" in my "test2" database using mongoose.

[image]

I am using nodeJS to perform the query

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');    
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://*****:*******b@cluster0-uln4x.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useNewUrlParser: true,
})
.then(() => console.log('DB Connected!!!'))
.catch(err => {
console.log('did not work');    });    
var db = mongoose.connection;   
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function() {
    db.dogs.find().forEach(printjson);     //ERROR!
 });
```

Which results in the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

How come dogs is `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `dogs` has to be a mongoose model, Also changed mongoDB connection string to `test2`, Please try this :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://*****:*******b@cluster0-uln4x.mongodb.net/test2?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
})
    .then(() => console.log('DB Connected!!!'))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('did not work', err);
    });
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

const dogsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    any: {}
});

const Dogs = mongoose.model('dogs', dogsSchema, 'dogs');

db.once('open', function () {
    Dogs.find().lean(true).exec((err, data) => {
        console.log('Err ::', err, 'data ::', data)
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works. However, it does seem strange that we need to create a new schema for this operation.

Comment: @cmote : We've to do & usually do create schemas in mongoose on a regular practice, Which is more helpful on writes..Please check this as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429630/querying-a-collection-without-passing-schema-in-mongoose