# How to use mongoose module in node.js to get one record from mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve data from MongoDB in nodejs. The items have slightly different structure ,so I do not want to use strict schema. My code is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const testDataSchema = new Schema({ any: {} })

const TestData = mongoose.model('my_collection_name', testDataSchema);

var url = "mongodb://myurl";

mongoose.connect(url);

mongoose.connection.once('open', function(){
    console.log('connected!!!');
}).on('error', function(error){
    console.log('error!!!', error);
});

TestData.findOne({}).then(function(result){
    console.log('Result', result);
})
```

It prints:

```
connected!!!
Result null
```

The collection defenitelly has many records. What is the problem here and how to resolve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429630/querying-a-collection-without-passing-schema-in-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 TestData.find(function (err, products) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    console.log(products);
 });
```

also make sure that TestData is a model object

Comment: It prints [] , because it is find and not findOne. But it is a same result. No error.