# typeErorr can not read property findOne of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to connect to external database exist on local via server.

In other words I want to get the Price Model which is exist in local mongodb database not in my server:

```
const mongooseLocal = require('mongoose');
const connectionOptions = { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false };
const conn = mongooseLocal.createConnection(config.MONGODB_URI_LOCAL, connectionOptions);
conn.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error: "));
conn.once("open", async () => {

  console.log("Connected successfully");
  const priceModel = await conn.Price.findOne({}); // Price is a Model in  local side and not exist in my server . it's on local...
  console.log('init', priceModel);

});
```

The issue is although I see the `"Connected successfully"` log but I cann't get the data..

I see this  error each time

> typeErorr can not read property findOne of undefined

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're trying to use `Price` property of connection. I think you should use model instead of connection.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ... I edited the question please have a look... And How should I use "model instead of connection" ?? I don't get it ?!

Comment: See my answer below. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `mongoose` your steps are:

1. Define model schema ( https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html )
2. Import model
3. Use model's `findOne` method

Example:

```js
// Price model (price.model.ts)
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const priceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});
exports.Price = mongoose.model('Price', priceSchema );

// index.ts (your file snippet)
const mongooseLocal = require('mongoose');
const { Price } = require('./price.model.ts');

const connectionOptions = { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false };
const conn = mongooseLocal.createConnection(config.MONGODB_URI_LOCAL, connectionOptions);
conn.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error: "));
conn.once("open", async () => {

  console.log("Connected successfully");
  const priceModel = await Price.findOne({}); 
  console.log('init', priceModel);
});
```

Comment: No... I don't have access to price Schema. Price is a model in local side , I want to just get it from server side !

Comment: Then take look at this similar question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429630/querying-a-collection-without-passing-schema-in-mongoose